# Java weird static import

Tags: java

```
package pack1;

public class A {

    public static int i = 10;
    public static void test()  {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

This is separate .class file:

```
package pack2;
import pack1.A.*;
public class Manager0  {

    public static void main(String args [] ) {

        System.out.println(A.i);
        A.test();
    }
}
```

When I run `Manager0` class it shows error because I used `import pack1.A.*;` instead of  `import pack1.A;`, but why doesn't `import pack1.A.*;` work? I mean doesn't `import pack1.A.*;` mean import everything in class `A`?

Comment: Guys, if you're downvoting, what keeps you away from posting a comment at least (Don't you have **keyboard**?). And I don't understand why so much of downvote on this question?

Comment: @RohitJain interestingly the duplicate found is also asked by same OP.. :) and no one downvoted that question. Btw I am not the downvoter.

Comment: The duplicate question has a pretty good answer with links to reading resources, also it has been marked as accepted. So, you already know what you have to do, go read and practice. This question seems to be an attempt to obtain more reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `static` imports. That should be:

```
import static pack1.A.*;
```

.. and you should really avoid it, specially using like that. If you want a specific member, import it specifically by using it's name.

It failed without `static` because you can't import members of a class non-statically. You can only use so called *Import-on-demand*, to import classes from a particular packages, or *static import-on-demand* to import `static` members of a class.

Comment: can u plz elaborate why this is not working.

Comment: You are missing a Java keyword, that is all.